# Selenium copy image to Base64 string?

Tags: image, selenium, selenium-webdriver, base64

How can I get an image on a webpage with Selenium and encode it to a Base64 string which gets added to a variable? I'm using Selenium C# but any language will probably work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are asking. What do you mean by "get an image on a webpage"? Do you mean:

1. grab a screenshot of your page and compare it with some given value? or
2. take a screenshot of specific element on webpage?
3. download an image contained in (ie) `<img>` tag and do something with it?

For taking screenshots, it is widely disucessed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver). Although mostly java solutions, they probably could be ported to C# with ease. If what you need is nr 3, then get the URL (ie using xpath `//img[@id=\"yourId\"]@src` ) and download it using something like [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and convert that to base64:

```
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  var baseString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

Comment: I am referring to option 3, the image in an `<img>` tag.

Comment: 1. get the image url. 

2. download it 

3. open the bytestream of the file 

4. convert it to base64. .

.. ... 

X. $$$profit$$$

Comment: What if the image URL expires after it is first loaded in the page? Is there a way to take it from the local loaded copy?

Comment: If the link is dead on the server, then you are out of luck with this approach. Anyway, you could possible take screenshot of that image. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver/21376753#21376753) . It is java implementation, but you can port it to C#. You could probably use the [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class by using the `Clone()` method.

Comment: Someone already implemented and shared. Check [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:x-X285hepOEJ:brantleytec.blogspot.com/2013/02/webdriver-screen-shot-in-c.html+&cd=3&hl=et&ct=clnk&gl=ee&client=firefox-a)

Answer (score 1):

This code will helps you, I am using it for my own report, instead of storing report in seperate location, better to convert into base64 form and add it to report.

```
   String Base64StringofScreenshot="";
    File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driverThread).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(src);
    Base64StringofScreenshot = "data:image/png;base64,"+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
```